# Nautilus encrypted file not asking for decryption password

Tags: nautilus, password, encryption

In Ubuntu 18.04 I encrypted a file in Nautilus (Files) using the right click 'Encrypt' menu selection. I use the 'Shared Passphrase' option and enter a password. I do not check the 'Save in password manager' box. The .pgp file is created as expected. 
When I want to decrypt the .pgp file I right click and select 'Open With Decrypt File'. I expect to be asked for a password but instead the file is opened directly. Can this be configured so that I have to enter a password to decrypt the file? 
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nautilus encrypted file opens save dialog instead of prompting for password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1393278/nautilus-encrypted-file-opens-save-dialog-instead-of-prompting-for-password)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and got a solution and explanation [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1393278/nautilus-encrypted-file-opens-save-dialog-instead-of-prompting-for-password).

## Explanation

When you assign the passphrase it is still remembered by GPG when you attempt to immediately open the file. In order to forget the passphrase you will need to log out of your Ubuntu computer or in some cases, reboot your machine. You can test this as follows:

### Test Steps

1. Encrypt the file as you have described. This should leave you with the original file as well as the `.pgp` file.
2. Delete the original file.
3. Log out of your computer.
4. Log back in and attempt to open the `.pgp` file.

### Expected Result

You should now be prompted for the passphrase that you created. Note that logging out may not work so you can also try rebooting your machine.

Comment: Two things. 1. This is the same link given in the comment. 2. Just a link is not considered an answer as what about later if the link is gone?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback David.  I've edited my response to include the actual explanation.