# Nautilus encrypted file opens save dialog instead of prompting for password

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, encryption, seahorse

In Ubuntu 18.04 I encrypted a LibreOffice file called 'test.odt' by right clicking and choosing the Encrypt option. I used the Shared Passphrase option rather than using a key. A new file was created called 'test.odt.pgp' but the original, unencrypted file was kept as well. When I attempt to open the 'test.odt.pgp' file, either by double clicking or by right clicking and selecting the Open with Decrypt File option, I am presented with the Save dialog instead of being prompted for a password. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password you assigned is still remembered by GPG when you create the `test.odt.pgp` file and open it **immediately**.

## To test:

1. Delete the file `test.odt`
2. log out of your Ubuntu computer.
3. log back in.
4. Double click on the file `test.odt.pgp`

Under some situation logging out and logging out and logging back in may not be enough. You may have to restart the computer.

Now you will be asked for the passphrase. The test.odt` will be recreated (decrypted) only if you can provide the right passphrase.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and steps to test.  Everything worked almost as you described.  The only difference being that logging out and back in didn't work.  I had to restart my machine for the password to be forgotten.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @HanzosFury thanks for the feedback. I am not sure why you had to restart your computer. Maybe you and I have different settings. I will add your experience to the answer.